# Detecting if cache was hit

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, weblogic12c

I have a webapp based on jee6 deployed on Weblogic.

I am using JPA (EclipseLink) and i enabled some entities with

```
@Cache(type = CacheType.SOFT, size = 10000, expiry = 360000)
```

Now how can i detect if the cache is used ? is there a way to have some cache hits statistics ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Writing a Cache Interceptor might be a way.
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.2/org/eclipse/persistence/sessions/interceptors/CacheInterceptor.html

If you're only looking for statistics, you might want to switch to OpenJPA which contains those out of the box
http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.2/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_caching.html

I think Weblogic's native JPA implementation is Kodo, which is based on OpenJPA (maybe an older version though) so you might find it there too.

Answer (score 1):

EclipseLink provides a performance profiler http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Performance_Monitoring_and_Profiling/Performance_Profiling

and monitoring http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Monitoring

My guess is the monitor is more what you are looking for.